# Wordpress gallery resizer preview picture is broken

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, image

I can't crop or resize manually my pictures in my Wordpress gallery with the included resizer.

I have only one theme I bought on themeforest, and all was working well until I decide to crop some preview pictures on my posts.

My WP is hosted on a vps with nginx. But I already tried some things like activating the php-gd module, and so on...

Here is what I have on my picture resizer :

[image: preview image link is broken...]

Here is something I didn't really understand, because the json file is send after the axaj call...

[image: In the web console, there is a mess...]

I hope you can help me to solve this issue, because theme's staff can't solve this issue (they're saying that all is working for them, and it comes from a plugin I installed), and no solutions on the wordpress community forum works for me...

Have a nice day!

#### EDIT : I add used plugin list as advised by Musk

---

- Akismet
- Awesome Weather Widget
- Jetpack for Wordpress
- BackWpUp
- Envato Wordpress Toolkit
- Wordpress Importer
- Max Mega Menu
- Responsive Lightbox
- SportPress
- Widget Importer & Exporter
- Woo Commerce
- Table Press

Comment: Since it is a wordpress related issue, you should list plugins that you use. Maybe someone had a similar issue caused by one of them. Also i had in the past had issue with ajax calls because of a corporate firewall flagging me has doing cross-site scripting.

Comment: Yes you're right, thanks. I just edited the issue with the full list of all plugins installed on my Wordpress.
Oh really? Maybe I need to check my firewall rules to check if nothing break ajax calls from my VPS!

Comment: Here is the same issue, Hope could be the help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043991/image-crop-editor-not-working