# install php70-gd on ubuntu

Tags: php, gd, php-7

Recently the new php7 has been released. However, when I am trying to install the gd package, the library can not be found.

I have tried through

```
sudo apt-get install php70-gd
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install php70-php-gd
```

Does anybody have an idea if gd is available for php 7?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

PHP7 packages for Ubuntu including `php7.0-gd` can be installed via [PPA for PHP by Ondřej Surý](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

Next, install the desired version:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
# or
sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd
# or
sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd
# or
sudo apt-get install php7.3-gd
# or
sudo apt-get install php7.4-gd
```

EDIT:

As [MacroMan stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367917/install-php70-gd-on-ubuntu#comment62835412_34369632), under Ubuntu 16.04 you don't need to add the repository any more. Simply issuing `sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd` works.

Comment: Under Ubuntu 16.04 you don't need to add the repository any more. Simply issuing `sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd` works

Comment: If you have php-7.x (eg: 7.1 use sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd)

Answer (score 19):

just try

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

i got it working that way.
Greetings.

Answer (score 17):

In 2018, there is an alias package for this:

`sudo apt-get install php-gd`

Use this to retrieve the last version.

Answer (score 6):

my php version is 7.1

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd
```

this command is work for me

Answer (score 1):

For
**Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS**

this is the command:

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd`

Answer (score 1):

check php verison first using

```
php -v
```

It will give version number suppose your version is 7.0.1 then use this command to install GD Library

```
 sudo yum install php70-gd
```

OR use this command depending upon server specification

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```