# How to install the php 7 gd extension on debian 8 jessie?

Tags: php, linux, debian, gd

Question answered for [Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367917/install-php70-gd-on-ubuntu) but not working for Debian because it's not available yet. When searching [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=php%20gd&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all) only packages for php 5 gd are available.

What's the preferred way of installing `php7.0-gd` in Debian 8 Jessie? What's the best unofficial source?

Answer (score 0):

[dotdeb.org](https://www.dotdeb.org/) appears to have it, install with [instructions](https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/). And run `apt-get update` and `apt-get install -y php7.0-gd`.

Answer (score 0):

It is available on version Stretch. This is the best **official** repo.

```
php7.0-gd:   Installed: (none)   Candidate:
 7.0.12-1   Version table:
      7.0.13-2 350
         350 http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian sid/main i386 Packages
      7.0.12-1 500
         500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch/main i386 Packages

echo 'deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch.list
```