# Installation of Magento 2 error: php ext-gd is required

Tags: php, magento, ubuntu, composer-php

I am trying to install `magento/product-community-edition 2.1.3` in `cloud9 (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS)` with `PHP 7.0.15`

I get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.3].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.3 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /home/ubuntu/.phpbrew/php/php-7.0.15/etc/php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I tried to do the following installation on [install php70-gd on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367917/install-php70-gd-on-ubuntu) but I still get the same error afterwards.

How will I successfully install magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

Use following command to install the **gd** extension:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd
```

it will work for PHP version 5.6

If you are using any other verison of PHP, replace 5.6 by that like:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

for PHP 7.0

Comment: you can find PHP version by running this command in ssh/terminal: **php -v**

Comment: I've already installed php gd and still get the same error `sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php7.0-gd is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 166 not upgraded.`

Comment: Then, check if in your php.ini file has the following line:

**;extension=php_gd2.dll**

if exists, change it to

**extension=php_gd2.dll**

and restart apache

Answer (score 0):

run

`sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd`

or

`sudo apt-get install phpX.X-gd`

then check your .ini files:

> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini
>   files:
>       - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

change

`;extension=...`

to `extension=...` for each dependency you need.

If the error is still there, check the PHP version on your localhost/server and the PHP version that you are using with your Magento.

Be aware that all versions of PHP are not compatible to Magento.

More informations: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/php-version.html

Good luck!

PS: If you got the same issue for ext-mcrypt, ext-dom or anything else, you will have to follow the same process and then re-run the composer installation.

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-dom`

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt`

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl`