# imagecreatefromjpeg not working after upgrading ubuntu to xenial

Tags: php, gd, ubuntu-16.04, php-7

After following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367917/install-php70-gd-on-ubuntu)
I still get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()

Checking php_info, GD is enabled already in my php 7.0 installation... any clues?

I had an Ubuntu 14.04 and after doing a release upgrade to `16.04` everything went nuts, and even after `apt-get install php7.0-gd` it is not working :(.

**Edit:**

Actually I see this on my info: GD imaging In module authors, but there is no actual GD section on the php_info() output, so something seems to be wrong with the process I followed and even tho I `apt-get install php7.0-gd`, it is not completely enabled? I'm checking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so stupid me, I thought module was enabled because apt-get went fine and I saw that GD imaging line on the php_info() output.

But actually the php_gd2 module was not enabled on my php.ini file, after double checking that and restarting apache everything works fine... sorry about that.