# How to fix problem when i install packages Maatwebsite/Excell on linux

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel, lampp

I want to install the maatwebsite / excell package on my project, but I got an error installing these packages on linux, When i run : composer update/install or composer require maatwebsite/excel, i found this error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.27, ..., 3.2.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.16 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0, 1.17.0, 1.17.1].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.26 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.15 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, 1.16.0, 1.17.0, 1.17.1].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.20, ..., 3.1.25] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.14 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.14.0, ..., 1.17.1].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.18, ..., 3.1.19] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.10 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.10.0, ..., 1.17.1].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.7, ..., 3.1.17] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.6 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.6.0, ..., 1.17.1].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.6] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.4 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.4.0, ..., 1.17.1].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.28, ..., 3.1.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.16.* -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0].
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.4.0, ..., 1.17.1] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
    - Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel ^3.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.2.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that ext-gd is missing.
You may install it using this command. It is for php 7.0. If you are using another version then please change it. For example for php 7.3, it would be php7.3-gd.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

For more information please visit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34367917/9539083)