# how to install gd lib for php7.4 using ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am using this command `sudo apt-get install php7.4-gd`

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-gd
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-gd'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-gd'
```

I am trying to install a `gd` library in php7.4 but can't install it. The above error is shown in the terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [install php70-gd on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367917/install-php70-gd-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Although the title of my suggested duplicate says php7.0, the accepted answer does show you how to install gd lib for php7.4

Comment: i have use below command.
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.4-gd (THIS IS NOT WORKING)

Comment: do you have the same error?

Comment: yes, i am trying this commnd and show below errors in php version 7.4
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-gd
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-gd'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-gd'

Comment: I'm just guessing that, since Ubuntu is based on Debian, version 7.4 of PHP isn't available yet on the stable branch. Check with `sudo apt search php7.4`. If that is the case, you'll need to install from an upstream repository. Preferrably from [Sury](https://deb.sury.org/).

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple

```
apt-get install php-gd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're Ubuntu version is < 16.04:

```
// Adding some compiled PHP extensions to your repository list
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

Then properly install the GD extension

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-gd
```