# Wordpress: Images Not Cropping After Move to S3

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, plugins

Originally, any featured image would be cropped to the same proportions for the widget areas of our theme. However, since the move to [Offload S3 Lite](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-s3/) this has stopped. Images are now displayed with their original proportions. Example: we’ll have a row of 4 images, but the one hosted on S3 is much taller than the other 3.

If you're interested you can see an image on my Wordpess-specific question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/301851/featured-images-no-longer-cropping-after-move-to-amazon-s3).

We are using the [Weta theme](https://www.elmastudio.de/en/themes/weta/) by Elma Studio. I’ve contacted their support as well since I am not sure which side is causing the problem.

Apologies as the page is currently in maintenance mode awaiting website launch and I’m unable to share the URL.

Is there some setting that might be causing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image Crop Editor Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043991/image-crop-editor-not-working)

Comment: ^ Not a duplicate. That issue seems tied to the cropping editor itself not working, this issue is tied to the cropping being overridden when the image is served from S3.