# Error : Image crop area preview. Requires mouse interaction - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Reference [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043991/image-crop-editor-not-working)

I have a fresh install but I am unable to edit/crop any images in WordPress. Every time I upload an image, after upload, the thumbnail is blank and when I proceed next, I get the same error every time.

`Image crop area preview. Requires mouse interaction`

**Edit: This error happens only when I try to upload a `.png` file**

Things I have tried :

- I have tried reinstalling multiple times.
- There is no `?>` at the end of the `functions.php` file as mentioned in multiple forums
- Gave `777` permissions to the whole directory of public_html
- Deleted the whole `.htaccess` file
- Its a fresh install, so no plugins involved. Some plugins were installed by default, I tried that too
- Works perfectly when I install locally

I dont know how to install `php5-gd` without a command line because I am installing WordPress on a hosting provider. But there is a extension called `gd` in my hpanel console. Its tooltip says its for working with images. I think its the same...(Its installed). `imagick` extension is also installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clean everything and fresh install WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Go to WordPress dashboard settings and media under uploading files, select the correct path of your domain in "Store uploads in this folder"